# Facebook SDK [4.6.0] duplicate symbols

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using:

FBSDKCoreKit - FBSDKLoginKit - FBSDKShareKit
(4.6.0 version)

I can't understand why today (was working till yesterday) I have 150 duplicate symbols like:

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/Jacopo/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/Jacopo/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject.o)
```

I tried reimport everything, I checked Build Phase, I updated my pods, can't solve it!

**EDIT:**
I just downgrade the SDK to 4.5.1 and everything works.
I was using 4.6 without problem the other day tho, weird!

**EDIT:**
I tried another project that's using Facebook SDK 4.6.0, same problem!
I downloaded again the SDK today, could be that they just released a new version with that bug?

Apparently there's just one beta of the SDK -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads

**WORKAROUND:**
Using Cocoapods works fine

Comment: Yesterday and today, you use the same Xcode?

Comment: Yeah i'm using Version 6.4 (tried with 7.0 beta 5 too, same error)

Comment: Same problems. In another project with cocoapods works fine, but in this I don't want to use cocoapods

Comment: same here today with 4.6.0

Comment: Downgrading to 4.5.1 worked for me. Check this SO post that contain the correct answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514962/linker-error-in-ios-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: 4.5.1 doesn't support iOS 9, no?!

Answer (score 1):

This thread https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/752177668227984/ explains you must compile the Facebook 4.6.0 SDK in Xcode 7 to resolve the issue. After compiling in Xcode 7 it worked for me.

In the Facebook iOS SDK 4.6.0, App Thinning (Bitcode) support has been added and therefore it cannot be complied in Xcode versions lower than Xcode 7.0.