# Linker Error in iOS (duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, linker-errors

I keep on getting the following error:

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
/Users/name/Documents/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKApplicationDelegate.o)
/Users/name/Documents/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKServerConfiguration.o)
ld: 102 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried deleting the FBSDK and reinstalling, but that has not work. I also suspect that the fact that I'm bridging the framework into Swift may be the problem. My bridging header contains the following:

```
#ifndef EggCrush_Bridge_h
#define EggCrush_Bridge_h

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

#endif
```

My AppDelegate.swift file imports FBSDKCoreKit.
There are no other linker flags.
I'm running Xcode 6.3.2 and building a project for iOS 8.3

How to clear this error up?

Comment: If can't do anything, try to update to Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do anything.

Comment: So weird. Did you try download and use another FBSDK?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned my old FBSDK from my hard drive, then created a new project and added the newly downloaded FBSDK.

Comment: I've got the same problem, were you able to solve it?

Comment: Not yet. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @simpleBob Try going back one version, that worked for me.

Comment: @Dan solved the problem by using Cocoapods to integrate it. `pod 'Bolts'`
`pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'`
`pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'`, I am also using parse, which needs `pod 'Parse'` and `pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'`

Comment: Upgrading to Xcode 7 solves this issue.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If not mistaken, you are using the sdk which just released by Facebook at September 10th, 2015 which named as [FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip). Try to use sdk that released at August 13th, 2015 which named as [FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip) and report to Facebook about the duplication problem if you can. Thank you.

Comment: This works. Make sure to remove any older reference to the 20150910 framework and/or remove the DerivedData cache.

Comment: This worked for me as well running xcode 6.4 on iOS 8.4 Simulator. Thanks so much

Comment: i get this only in simulator :((

Comment: Yes this is because the latest one is supported with App Thining. so It would work in Xcode 7

Comment: Is FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip compatible with iOS9 ?

Comment: Yes is works but what is the problem? could you explain me.

Comment: Does  FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip work for iOS 9 as well cause for iOS 9 I changed to  FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip and facing this issue!!!Its compiling for device not simulator. will this be a problem?

Comment: @It_Does_Not_Matter did you find your answer cause I am facing the same issue, I ca not make the FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip work with iOS 9, it does not return result!!

Answer (score 25):

[This thread](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/752177668227984/) explains you must compile the Facebook 4.6.0 SDK in Xcode 7 to resolve the issue. After compiling in Xcode 7 it worked for me.

In the Facebook iOS SDK 4.6.0, App Thinning (Bitcode) support has been added and therefore it cannot be complied in Xcode versions lower than Xcode 7.0.

Comment: @Guan Chuan and Aravind Mariappan Answers should be merged!

Answer (score 2):

When I had a duplicate symbols error, I opened my project.xcodeproj XML file in a text editor and searched the duplicate symbol. You'll most likely find that FacebookSDK shows up in multiple lines with the same "id" property. Make sure you have a back up of your current project, and try deleting the duplicates (ones that have the same id) manually in this file. Save the file, compile, and see if the project runs.

You might want to try just deleting one duplicate line, and seeing if the number of duplicates (apparently you have 102!!) goes down first.

Comment: I actually don't see any instances of FacebookSDK. Is it supposed to be there automatically?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use **FacebookSDKs-iOS-20160115.zip** and your XCODE Version**XCODE 6.4** or lower version of **XCODE** then this type of issue create.
2. **FacebookSDKs-iOS-20160115.zip** this is use for **XCODE 7**.
3. You can use **https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip**.
4. Its work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue of duplicate symbols. I was using **Xcode 6.4** but later when I upgraded to **Xcode 7.0** It Worked fine for me. I would suggest to Upgrade your **Xcode to 7.0** if you are using earlier one.