# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 (Implementing FBSDKCoreKilt) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, linker-errors

This is the most horrifying error that I've dealt with so far.  To be clear:

1. This is in swift so it's not a ".h" ".m" issue
2. My compile sources is so tiny, there are no duplicates there.
3. I have redownloaded the SDK several times but it never works.
4. The project only has two frameworks in it: FBSDKCoreKit and LoginKit

Any ideas? What is duplicated?

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginCompletion.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginCompletion.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginConstants.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginConstants.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginError.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginError.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManager.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManager.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginTooltipView.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginTooltipView.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginUtility.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginUtility.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKTooltipView.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKTooltipView.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(_FBSDKLoginRecoveryAttempter.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(_FBSDKLoginRecoveryAttempter.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManagerLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginManagerLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKGraphRequestPiggybackManager.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKGraphRequestPiggybackManager.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAppEventsStateManager.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAppEventsStateManager.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKServerConfigurationManager.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKServerConfigurationManager.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKGraphRequest.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKGraphRequest.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKContainerViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKContainerViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessTokenCache.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessTokenCache.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKCrypto.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKCrypto.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAppEventsState.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAppEventsState.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKCloseIcon.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKCloseIcon.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKBase64.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKBase64.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKBridgeAPIProtocolWebV2.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKBridgeAPIProtocolWebV2.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKGraphRequestBody.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKGraphRequestBody.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKUtility.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKUtility.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKBoltsMeasurementEventListener.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKBoltsMeasurementEventListener.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)
    /Users/charleswesleycho/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKApplicationDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:

ld: 142 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What's the version of your Facebook SDK?

Comment: Newest version v4.6.0

Comment: I would suggest trying the previous one first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads or try to install latest Bolts version separetly

Comment: Changed to the older version, still didn't work.

Comment: Then try to install Bolts manually into your project. Have no more ideas.

Comment: I deleted the branch I was working on and started from scratch again with the older SDK and now it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Its an issue with the latest Facebook SDK (Sept 10th 2015). Download the release before it.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32519847/1052084 which worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even the new SDK I have downloaded (20151007) has the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

thanks this working with me when using facebook SDK https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by any included static libraries or sub-projects that are included with your project, having a different target version ie. you have an externalSourcesLibrary project and it's build target is set to minimum version 6.0 while your main project is set to something higher like 8.4 or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by removing manually imported FBSDK dependencies (from Link Binary with libraries) and adding following lines to pod file:

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```