# IOS Facebook login through the app

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift, facebook-login

I'm trying to implements a facebook login into my app.

I've watched and read a lot of tutorials for iOS 8+ and Swift. The problem is that all tutorials seems to login through the safari and not Facebook app.

Is there some way to implements it using latest Facebook IOS SDK through the Facebook app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment the FBSDK 4.x does not support login with FacebookApp.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32593070/4755417
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/?search_id

You can use FacebookSDK 3.x

Comment: thanks so much for help. I looked for explanations why is not possible use the app instead safari and found many answers that were working around UX.