# Login with facebook with native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I need to facebook login via custom button.

So I made following method.

```
- (IBAction)loginWithFBClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;

    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error:%@",error);
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             HomeViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
         }
     }];
}
```

After that I check in real device (iPhone 5s(iOS 9.0)) but It is opening browser for login.
I have installed and logged in facebook app in my device.
though I am facing this problem.
Please help me.

Comment: `login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;` comment this line and check and run

Comment: It is not opening a browser for login.  It is displaying a webpage within your app.  The simplest way to tell is that you don't get a prompt to switch apps (which is why FB changed the implementation for iOS 9).

Comment: first that was the code.But faced this problem So, I added this line.

Comment: @Avi,Can I get reference of that information??

Comment: Which information?  The behavior or the reason?  The behavior is obvious; I already gave a simple way to verify it.  The reason is speculation on my part, but if you can come up with a better reason, run with it.

Comment: Yes, I'll verify on iOS 8.4...

Comment: @Avi Check this out, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566734/native-facebook-app-does-not-open-with-facebook-login-in-ios-9

Comment: yes, That I already visited.

Comment: @Moseph, Yes on iOS 9 and iOS 9.1. Using FBSDK 4.7.1

Answer (score 1):

I noticed following changelogs:

[Facebook SDK for iOS Changelog v4.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x)

> (v4.6.0 - September 10, 2015) In addition, the SDK dialogs such as
>   Login, Like, Share Dialogs automatically determine the best UI based
>   on the device, including SFSafariViewController instead of Safari.
>   Follow the our Preparing for iOS 9 guide.

Comment: Following iOS 9  guide is just different that we need to add more key and values(array) of transport security and application query schemes. I also followed that

Comment: you don't open native app becz..facebook depricate that thing...facebook replace sfsafariViewcontroller

Comment: if you want to open native app then use old sdk.

Comment: @Moseph what about iOS 8.x version using the same sdk(4.x)?