# Facebook button open in safari rather than app

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, safari

I have a Facebook button in my app which is linked to my Facebook page however it open up in safari rather than the Facebook app. I have also linked twitter that opens up in the app first and not safari which is how i want it. My code for both buttons is the same so i don't understand why it is behaving this way?

```
   @IBAction func openFB(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/XXXXXXXXX")!) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/XXXXXXXXX")!)
} else {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://facebook.com/XXXXXXXX")!)
}
 }



@IBAction func openTW(sender: AnyObject) {

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "tw://profile/XXXXXXX")!) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/XXXXXXXX")!)
} else {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/XXXXXXXXXX")!)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is happening after `iOS 9`. you will find how to resolve this by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998108/1186689)

Hope this will help.