# Facebook SDK login issue in iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x, ios9.2

I am using facebook login in my app. It is not working in iOS9.2. After facebook login the safari window is not redirecting to my app and it is showing a blank screen. It is working fine in iOS 9 and other versions. Please find the screenshots below.
[image]

I have followed the instructions described in this stackover flow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998108 for configuring facebook SDK.

Please help me out.

Comment: Even i am facing the same situation when viewing web view it works fine in login action     FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;  // it open inside the app using popup menu

Comment: Use this sdk that will solve your problem : https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150708.pkg

Comment: @UmaMadhavi : Thank you so much.. The issues  is solved :)