# How To refresh FBSDK Access Token From iOS APP

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, fbsdkloginkit

I am using `FBSDKLoginKit` in my app for the authentication purpose of the user.

I need to keep the user logged in unless and until user specifically choose to log out from app.

For this I need to refresh the `FBSDKLoginKit` token without showing user the login screen.

So can any one help how i can achieve it?

> **EDIT**

I want user to login only once and let user use the application directly when user comes back on another day. As FBSDK token get's expired in 60 Days so need a way to refresh automatically when user comes back to app

> **EDIT2**

I found one method named `refreshCurrentAccessToken`but it's still unclear how to use it as not sure when to call it.

Comment: it would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566734/native-facebook-app-does-not-open-with-facebook-login-in-ios-9

Comment: @Sanjeetverma i am getting user info and all required details.

i have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Facebook doc. The access token will be refreshed automatically per day if you make requests to Facebook server.

> Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived access tokens, good for about 60 days. **These tokens will be refreshed once per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers**. If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to get a new token.