# iOS - How to enable Facebook Login without hardcoding the values in info.plist file

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, apple-push-notifications

**Background:**
We provide users an option to create mobile application for their eCommerce store. They can choose what type of changes need to be done and then we go ahead and create the app for them. *It is all smooth except for the pain point* with getting the Facebook APIs keys generated by the users. Most of the times they do not pay attention and create wrong keys and then we have to tell them to create again. This takes a lot of to-n-fro and wastes time.

**What we intend to achieve:**
We have been able to do this successfully in Android but not with iOS. We want to give the users an interface in their web panel to enter the API keys. This would allow us to deliver the application to the users very fast and then they can work at their end to generate the API keys by going through the tutorials at their own leisure.

*We have tried playing with info.plist file but it is not editable on the run time. So we need to find out another way to solve the issue.*

Any help will be appreciated.

This is same thing we want to do with Google Login too.

Comment: Maybe generate the plist file dynamically, so they can download it after they input their app details, and place it in their project folder …?

Comment: Its a complete package which has to be prepared and uploaded to Appstore. We would not have option to make the changes as suggested by you.