# Duplicate Symbols FB Audience Network iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-audience-network

I am getting multiple (116) duplicate symbols when using Facebook's Audience Network SDK for iOS along the lines of:

> duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
>       /Users/myapp/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBInterstitialAd.o)
>    /Users/myapp/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
>       /Users/myapp/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBInterstitialAd.o)
>       /Users/myapp/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o)

Any suggestions as to where I could begin to rectify the problem?

Comment: Has the framework been added twice by accident?

Comment: I have removed and added it, so possibly?  Is there a definitive way to tell other than looking at the frameworks in Xcode?

Comment: Check it's not duplicated in either of these two sections: http://mindfusion.eu/_samples/diagram_setting1.png

If it's an embedded binary, it should be present in both of the sections

Comment: Nothing in embedded binaries, and no duplicate.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6? This answer suggests it might be they've released an Xcode 7 only framework: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32589186/78496

Comment: I am using 6.  I will look into either an older SDK, or updating Xcode.

Comment: I switched to the previous SDK and all is good!  Thank you chedabob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  **Guan Chuan's**  ans in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514962/linker-error-in-ios-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Try, [FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip) facebook sdk instead of  [FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip)