# Swift Facebook login Error "Apple Mach-O Linker Error"

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, sdk, compiler-errors

For some reason I get this error **"Apple Mach-O Linker Error [Linker command failed with exit code 1]"** when building the project after I add the code lines to the AppDelegate file. It builds perfectly until then.

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwLiE.png)

I also tested the Scrumptious app that comes in the FacebookSDK folder as a tester, and it gave me the same error.

Thus, I think it might be some problem with the installation of the sdk into Users/{username}/Documents/FacebookSDK. I literally just download the zip file Facebook provided, unziped, named it to FacebookSDK and pasted this folder in /Documents

Please, any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app doesn't support BitCode, you need to install an old version released at August 13th, 2015 which is named FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip

More info here:
[Linker Error in iOS (duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514962/linker-error-in-ios-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)