# Xcode - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am a noob in Xcode at this moment, I try to run one poject with Emulator but I receive this error:

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/dpulgarin/Projects/runator-ios/Runator/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
    /Users/dpulgarin/Projects/runator-ios/Runator/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKServerConfiguration.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/dpulgarin/Projects/runator-ios/Runator/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
    /Users/dpulgarin/Projects/runator-ios/Runator/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKServerConfiguration.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/dpulgarin/Projects/runator-ios/Runator/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
    /Users/dpulgarin/Projects/runator-ios/Runator/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKMaleSilhouetteIcon.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/dpulgarin/Projects/runator-ios/Runator/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
    /Users/dpulgarin/Projects/runator-ios/Runator/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKMaleSilhouetteIcon.o)
ld: 184 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea what might happen, I would like help to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an issue with the latest Facebook SDK (Sept 10th 2015). Download the release before it.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32519847/1052084 which worked for me.