# Integrate AppLovin With swift xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, applovin

I want to integrate `AppLovin` With Xcode 6.4 and swift. I am Following the steps which are given in Documentation. I have added Headers and `libAppLovinSdk.a` Library in my project. Then I have added all the frameworks which are needed and added AppLovin SDK key into info.plist file. Then I have initialized `ALSdk.initializeSdk()` in `Appdelegate.h` file and I have added Bridging file in my project. Then I wrote -Objc in "Other Linker Flags"

I am getting this error

> ld: 150 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

EDIT:

This is the error log.

[image: Error Log]

Comment: There are some duplicate files in the project. Please provide full error log, so filename can be identified

Comment: I have updated my question with image

Comment: Try removing -ObjC flag. Clean and build

Comment: Getting same error. I have initialized ALSdk.initializeSdk() in appdelegate.swift. If I will remove it than this error will not be displayed. But I need to initialize this.

Comment: Make sure you have followed steps properly for adding files and framework. I don't have AppLovin account, else I would have checked steps

Comment: I have checked it twice..

Comment: In which method you are invoking `ALSdk.initializeSdk()`?

Comment: Inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Initialize it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`. It should solve the problem.

Comment: No.. It is giving the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the linker errors (`duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module`) as well as the fact that you're using an older Xcode version, it may likely be a conflict/mismatch between the target/compiler of your project and the dependency. [This isn't inherent to AppLovin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32719178/220307), but can happen if the static library you're using is far too new or old for your Xcode version.

One possible occurrence of this is that we started compiling the library with Bitcode support, and I wouldn't be surprised if older versions of LLVM don't play nice with that.

I'd recommend pulling the latest version of `libAppLovinSdk.a`, and if at all possible, building using Xcode 7+.

Additionally, if you're using some dependency manager like Cocoapods or Carthage, you may have better luck directly (manually) integrating, given that [they are maintained by third parties with no involvement from us.](https://github.com/AppLovin/iOS-Demo-App/issues/3)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing SDK at wrong place. At the time of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` call, application has not been fully prepared. Try initializing it in method:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Also include `-ObjC` flag. It should solve duplicate symbols issue.